# Split a list with different number of elements into separate columns in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, list

I am extracting results from SQL Queries into my Pandas data frame. The results are either 'Min and Max' or Min, Max, and Average'.

[image: Min Max Data frame]

I want to split the Results column into separate columns in the existing data frame. I tried the below code

```
df[["Max","Min", "Average"]] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series({"Min_value": x[-1][0], "Max_value": x[-1][1], "Avg_value": x[-1][2]}), axis=1)
```

Sample Output:

```
Data = {'SQL_Query': ['SELECT MIN([Batch_Date_Time]) as Min_value, MAX([Batch_Date_Time]) as Max_value FROM [dbo].[dq_account]', 'SELECT MIN([Trxn_amt]) as Min_value, MAX([Trxn_amt]) as Max_value, AVG([Trxn_amt]) as Avg_value FROM [dbo].[dq_trxn]', 'SELECT MIN([Trxn_date]) as Min_value, MAX([Trxn_date]) as Max_value FROM [dbo].[dq_trxn]'],
                  'Results': ['[2019-04-01 00:00:00, 2099-04-30 00:00:00]', '[-1991.0, 8910.22, 1912.4404615384615]', '[2019-04-01, 2099-04-30]'],
                  'Min':  ['2019-04-01 00:00:00', '-1991.0', '2019-04-01'],
                  'Max': ['2099-04-30 00:00:00', '8910.22', '2099-04-30'],
                  'Avg': ['NA', '1912.4404615384615', 'NA']}

df = pd.DataFrame(Data,columns= ['SQL_Query', 'Results', 'Min', 'Max', 'Avg'])
```

But since, element '2' does not exist in the result for query 1 and 3, I get an error - IndexError: ('row index out of range index=2 len=2', 'occurred at index 0')

I don't understand how to resolve this error.

Comment: Curious, why is the second query mixed in with the first and third? Could you add some data example of what you are dealing with and also an example of what you are trying to accomplish? And please please don't attach pictures. Thanks.

Comment: 2nd Query is mixed with the other 2 because I'd like to have one file with all the queries rather than separate files for queries with separate formats. I'll try to add an example of the data I am dealing with but I am not sure it'll be helpful since it's just a mockup. I've updated the question with a sample of the output. Hope that helps? Thanks!

Comment: Is the dtype of 'Results' a string or a list?  The sample data output shows it as a string.

Comment: It is a list. Since, I created the data frame it might be showing it to be a string. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL query is always ordered : First max then min then Average, you can do :

```
def _split(x):
   max_=None if len(x)==2 else x[2]
   return pd.Series({"Min_value": x[0], "Max_value": x[1], "Avg_value": max_})

df[["Max","Min", "Average"]] = df['Results'].apply(lambda x: _split(x),axis=1)
```

otherwise you have to parse the query for every row to determine the order

Comment: Yes, it is always ordered. this should have worked but I got an error: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Answer (score 0):

In your DF above, I've changed the dates to strings in a list. A vectorized solution is provided by tolist().

```
pd.concat([df['SQL_Query'],pd.DataFrame(df.Results.values.tolist(), columns=['Min', 'Max', 'Avg'])], axis=1)



    SQL_Query           Min                     Max                     Avg
0   SELECT MIN([Bat...  2019-04-01 00:00:00     2099-04-30 00:00:00     NaN
1   SELECT MIN([Trx...  -1991                   8910.22                 1912.440461
2   SELECT MIN([Trx...  2019-04-01              2099-04-30              NaN
```

**EDIT**

I should have included the detail of changing your data as per your comments above. I've modified the data to make it a list instead of one string.

```
 "Results": [
        ["2019-04-01 00:00:00", "2099-04-30 00:00:00"],
        [-1991.0, 8910.22, 1912.440461],
        ["2019-04-01", "2099-04-30"],
    ],
```

If you haven't changed this then you will get the error mentioned in your comment. Furthermore, I'm certain the dates will likely be datetime objects, not strings as I've shown. But this should not effect the results.

Comment: Hey, not sure why but I got this error: ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 3), indices imply (3, 3)

Comment: See edit to reflect your comments regarding the data being a list, not a string.

Comment: Did this help? If answered your question, could you please select as the answer?